# @types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(483,22): error TS1005: ';'

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash, windows-server-2012-r2

Trying to figure out why the project builds correctly locally but fails on the build server

On both machines I use the same package.json

```
  "name": "UDP",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "buildProd": "ng build --prod",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.150",
    "ag-grid": "7.1.0",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "7.1.2",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-stormpath": "^0.1.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-toaster": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "1.7.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "dragula": "^3.7.2",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "flot": "^0.8.0-alpha",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.3.2",
    "jquery.browser": "^0.1.0",
    "jquery.flot.tooltip": "github:krzysu/flot.tooltip",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^1.4.10",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-table": "^1.3.2",
    "ng2-validation": "^3.1.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "protractor": "^4.0.14",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "screenfull": "^3.0.2",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.0.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.116",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.0.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "karma-typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.8.2"
  }
}
```

I clean up node_modules before build happens (using the following script - `rm -r node_modules`).

Getting the following after `ng build --prod`:
`@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(483,22): error TS1005: ';'`

Angular5 + Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `npm` version to the latest and generate `package-lock.json` file with this command:

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

to properly handle dependencies and their versions.